# I cannot view the transcript of every video on youtube which has closed captions

Tags: youtube

Roughly 10% of the time, closed-captioning exists on youtube but the transcript of those subtitles do not, however, the ratio is much worse with Arabic, maybe 50%.  This video for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X7SZzJwNcU&ab_channel=ANGAMFORMEDIA

and this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwOjb_ZJMUA&ab_channel=ANGAMFORMEDIA

and this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKb0xeHfIA&ab_channel=AlJazeeraMubasher%D9%82%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A9%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%B1

You can simply push the 3 dots and hit 'show transcript' because it's not there, nor is it at the bottom of the 'show more' tab.

I think this started happening after youtube started placing the transcript at the bottom of the "show more" tab.  If we're able to write software to download videos and if we're able to write software to extract subtitles from Netflix then it should be the case that we should be able to do with youtube.

Some people have trouble figuring out that when I say I can't do x, that implies I'm asking how do you do x, so for those that don't understand that let me make it clear that I want to know how to get the transcript for youtube videos which have closed captioning but the 'show transcript' button is not visible.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/yt-dlp/issues/1) are my current investigations concerning this issue.

Comment: This API solves the problem  https://pypi.org/project/youtube-transcript-api/